# Special characters insertion into PostgreSQL with dotConnectForPostgreSQL provider

Tags: postgresql, devart, dotconnect

As part of requirement, we have to insert special characters data into PostgreSQL table by using c# queries(ORM). Getting the error while committing the trasnaction.

"invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc3 0x5f"

Special characters: Ã_Ã

Query:
INSERT INTO XXXXXXX(key,  file_name, file_path,  source_id) VALUES (E'XXXX',  E'Ã_Ã', ‘Ã_Ã.xlsx',  XXX5)

.Net framwork 4.61.
PostgreSQl 11
nHibernate
C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add "Unicode=true;" to your connection string. Refer to [https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?Devart.Data.PostgreSql~Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlConnection~ConnectionString.html](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?Devart.Data.PostgreSql%7EDevart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlConnection%7EConnectionString.html).